# Got issue in acessing url from outside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container inside which Prometheus metrics is running on port 127.0.0.1:9615

I want to access those metrics from my host machine so I did the port binding 0.0.0.0:9615->9615. But still not able to curl that url localhost:9615/metrics gives me a response

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

My docker-compose file looks like that

```
version: '2'

services:
  polkadot:
    container_name: polkadot
    image: parity/polkadot
    ports:
      - 30333:30333 # p2p port
      - 9933:9933 # rpc port
      - 9944:9944 # ws port
      - 9615:9615
    command: [
      "--name", "PolkaDocker",
      "--ws-external",
      "--rpc-external",
      "--rpc-cors", "all"
    ]
```

What mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pulling down your `docker-compose.yaml` it seems like you were just missing one additional CLI flag `--prometheus-external`.

Updated docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  polkadot:
    container_name: polkadot
    image: parity/polkadot
    ports:
      - 30333:30333 # p2p port
      - 9933:9933 # rpc port
      - 9944:9944 # ws port
      - 9615:9615
    command: [
      "--name", "PolkaDocker",
      "--ws-external",
      "--rpc-external",
      "--rpc-cors", "all",
      "--prometheus-external" # NEW FLAG HERE
    ]
```

Now if you hit `localhost:9615/metrics` you should see data:

```
# HELP polkadot_block_height Block height info of the chain
# TYPE polkadot_block_height gauge
polkadot_block_height{status="best"} 0
polkadot_block_height{status="finalized"} 0
# HELP polkadot_block_verification_and_import_time Time taken to verify and import blocks
# TYPE polkadot_block_verification_and_import_time histogram
polkadot_block_verification_and_import_time_bucket{le="0.005"} 1076
...
```

Based on the CLI `polkadot --help` the flag is described like so:

```
$ polkadot --help
polkadot 0.9.8-3a10ee63c-x86_64-linux-gnu

Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>
Polkadot Relay-chain Client Node

USAGE:
    polkadot [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]
    polkadot <SUBCOMMAND>

FLAGS:
...
--prometheus-external
    Listen to all Prometheus data source interfaces.

    Default is local.
```

Comment: I got another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68674413/prometheus-metrics-end-point-is-running-but-the-target-status-is-down. Can you check that?